# Determining mining output from hashrate

Tags: mining, hashrate

I am trying to wrap my head around how to calculate how much ETH one would earn from mining based on hashrate.

For example, my RX 480 generates around 24Mh/s.  I would like to be able to calculate how much ETH would be generated from mining, based on that hashrate.  I would also like to include transactions and uncle blocks in the calculation, if possible.

Yes, I know there are online ETH calculators out there.  I'm trying to understand how to calculate it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Calculator use network diff and calculate how many percent of this network you will be and it give you this percant of all the reward collected in one day if you would know for 1 day or for 3 month for 3 month.
(This is the base but some calculator (very rare) calculate things like luck and probability to find a block or pool or network diff evolution)